# What to do if a company starts sending abusive newsletters years after having asked them to stop?

Tags: gdpr, spam, email-marketing

Five years ago, I used my e-mail address once to buy a service from a company in the EU (so the GDPR applies). Since then, they subscribed me without asking to a newsletter and sent me several mails per week. I had to contact them several times to ask to stop sending me any mail, and to delete my personal data.

This week, they have subscribed me again to a newsletter, without me having contacted them since. This is again highly unwanted, but also shows that they have not deleted my personal data. Is there a way to enforce them to finally delete my personal data, other than sending again several mails to ask it, and maybe be recontacted in five years?

Comment: You use the `gdpr` tag. Do you live in a country, where gdpr or similar applies?

Answer (score 2):

GDPR is an European regulation, but enforcement is left to the [national authorities](https://edpb.europa.eu/about-edpb/about-edpb/members_en). Those would be your first point of contact, especially if it is unclear *to you* where the offender is legally registered.